# M95128-W EEPROM. First byte of each page not writing or reading correctly

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm32, spi, eeprom

I am working on a library for controlling the [M95128-W EEPROM](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/11/47/cf/4a/88/23/42/87/CD00001441.pdf/files/CD00001441.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00001441.pdf) from an STM32 device. I have the library writing and reading back data however the first byte of each page it not as expected and seems to be fixed at `0x04`.

For example I write 128 bytes across two pages starting at `0x00` address with value `0x80`. When read back I get:

```
byte[0] = 0x04;
byte[1] = 0x80;
byte[2] = 0x80;
byte[3] = 0x80;
.......
byte[64] = 0x04;
byte[65] = 0x80;
byte[66] = 0x80;
byte[67] = 0x80;
```

I have debugged the SPI with a logic analyzer and confirmed the correct bytes are being sent. When using the logic analyzer on the read command the mysterios `0x04` is transmitted from the EEPROM.

Here is my code:

```
void FLA::write(const void* data, unsigned int dataLength, uint16_t address)
{
    int pagePos = 0;
    int pageCount = (dataLength + 64 - 1) / 64;
    int bytePos = 0;
    int startAddress = address;

    while (pagePos < pageCount)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_SET); // WP High
        chipSelect();

        _spi->transfer(INSTRUCTION_WREN);
        chipUnselect();

        uint8_t status = readRegister(INSTRUCTION_RDSR);

        chipSelect();

        _spi->transfer(INSTRUCTION_WRITE);
        uint8_t xlow = address & 0xff;
        uint8_t xhigh = (address >> 8);
        _spi->transfer(xhigh); // part 1 address MSB
        _spi->transfer(xlow); // part 2 address LSB


        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 64 && bytePos < dataLength; i++ )
        {
            uint8_t byte = ((uint8_t*)data)[bytePos];
            _spi->transfer(byte);

            printConsole("Wrote byte to ");
            printConsoleInt(startAddress + bytePos);
            printConsole("with value ");
            printConsoleInt(byte);
            printConsole("\n");

            bytePos ++;
        }

        _spi->transfer(INSTRUCTION_WRDI);

        chipUnselect();
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_RESET); //WP LOW

        bool writeComplete = false;
        while (writeComplete == false)
        {
            uint8_t status = readRegister(INSTRUCTION_RDSR);

            if(status&1<<0)
            {
                printConsole("Waiting for write to complete....\n");
            }

            else
            {
                writeComplete = true;
                printConsole("Write complete to page ");
                printConsoleInt(pagePos);
                printConsole("@ address ");
                printConsoleInt(bytePos);
                printConsole("\n");
            }
        }

        pagePos++;
        address = address + 64;
    }

    printConsole("Finished writing all pages total bytes ");
    printConsoleInt(bytePos);
    printConsole("\n");
}
void FLA::read(char* returndata, unsigned int dataLength, uint16_t address)
{
    chipSelect();
          _spi->transfer(INSTRUCTION_READ);
            uint8_t xlow = address & 0xff;
                    uint8_t xhigh = (address >> 8);
          _spi->transfer(xhigh); // part 1 address
          _spi->transfer(xlow); // part 2 address

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dataLength; i++)
                returndata[i] = _spi->transfer(0x00);
               chipUnselect();


}
```

Any suggestion or help appreciated.

**UPDATES:**

I have tried writing sequentially 255 bytes increasing data to check for rollover. The results are as follows:

```
byte[0] = 4; // Incorrect Mystery Byte 
byte[1] = 1; 
byte[2] = 2;
byte[3] = 3; 
....... 
byte[63] = 63; 
byte[64] = 4; // Incorrect Mystery Byte 
byte[65] = 65; 
byte[66] = 66;
....... 
byte[127] = 127; 
byte[128] = 4; // Incorrect Mystery Byte 
byte[129} = 129;
```

Pattern continues. I have also tried writing just 8 bytes from address 0x00 and the same problem persists so I think we can rule out rollover.

I have tried removing the debug printConsole and it has had no effect.

Here is a SPI logic trace of the write command:

[image]

And a close up of the first byte that is not working correctly:

[image]

Code can be viewed on gitlab here:
https://gitlab.com/DanielBeyzade/stm32f107vc-home-control-master/blob/master/Src/flash.cpp

Init code of SPI can be seen here in MX_SPI_Init()

https://gitlab.com/DanielBeyzade/stm32f107vc-home-control-master/blob/master/Src/main.cpp

I have another device on the SPI bus (RFM69HW RF Module) which works as expected sending and receiving data.

Comment: Maybe provide `FLA::read` too?

Comment: I have added thank you.

Comment: Side note - here's a code that works with such EEPROMs, tested with a similar device to yours (M95512) - https://github.com/DISTORTEC/distortos/blob/master/source/devices/memory/SpiEeprom.cpp https://github.com/DISTORTEC/distortos/blob/master/include/distortos/devices/memory/SpiEeprom.hpp

Comment: Your code is incomplete (no SPI initialization, no internal functions, no EXACT usage example, ...), so it's really hard to help you here...

Comment: Please see here in the MX_SPI1_Init() https://gitlab.com/DanielBeyzade/stm32f107vc-home-control-master/blob/master/Src/main.cpp

Comment: I should add on my board I have another module on the same SPI bus, an RFM69HW RF Module, that is confirmed working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation was actually already given by Craig Estey in his answer. You do have a rollover. You write full page and then - without cycling the CS pin - you send INSTRUCTION_WRDI command. Guess what's the binary code of this command? If you guessed that it's `4`, then you're absolutely right.

Check your code here:

```
    chipSelect();

    _spi->transfer(INSTRUCTION_WRITE);
    uint8_t xlow = address & 0xff;
    uint8_t xhigh = (address >> 8);
    _spi->transfer(xhigh); // part 1 address MSB
    _spi->transfer(xlow); // part 2 address LSB


    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 64 && bytePos < dataLength; i++ )
    {
        uint8_t byte = ((uint8_t*)data)[bytePos];
        _spi->transfer(byte);

        // ...

        bytePos ++;
    }

    _spi->transfer(INSTRUCTION_WRDI); // <-------------- ROLLOEVER!

    chipUnselect();
```

With these devices, each command MUST start with cycling CS. After CS goes low, the first byte is interpreted as command. All remaining bytes - until CS is cycled again - are interpreted as data. So you cannot send multiple commands in a single "block" with CS being constantly pulled low.

Another thing is that you don't need WRDI command at all - after the write instruction is terminated (by CS going high), the WEL bit is automatically reset. See page 18 of the datasheet:

> The Write Enable Latch (WEL) bit, in fact, becomes reset by any of the
> following events:
>
> • Power-up
>
> • WRDI instruction execution
>
> • WRSR instruction completion
>
> **• WRITE instruction completion.**

Comment: Simply removing _spi->transfer(INSTRUCTION_WRDI) fixed the problem. I did know this, but was just overlooking the code. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

*Caveat:* I don't have a definitive solution, just some observations and suggestions [that would be too large for a comment].

> From 6.6: Each time a new data byte is shifted in, the least significant bits of the internal address counter are incremented. If more bytes are sent than will fit up to the end of the page, a condition known as “roll-over” occurs. In case of roll-over, the bytes exceeding the page size are overwritten from location 0 of the same page.

So, in your write loop code, you do: `for (i = 0;  i < 64;  i++)`. This is incorrect in the general case if the LSB of address (`xlow`) is non-zero. You'd need to do something like: `for (i = xlow % 64;  i < 64;  i++)`

In other words, you *might* be getting the page boundary rollover. But, you mentioned that you're using address 0x0000, so it *should* work, even with the code as it exists.

I might remove the print statements from the loop as they could have an effect on the serialization timing.

I might try this with an incrementing data pattern: (e.g.) 0x01,0x02,0x03,... That way, you could see which byte is rolling over [if any].

Also, try writing a *single* page from address zero, and write *less* than the full page size (i.e. less that 64 bytes) to *guarantee* that you're not getting rollover.

Also, from figure 13 [the timing diagram for WRITE], it looks like once you assert chip select, the ROM wants a continuous bit stream clocked precisely, so you may have a race condition where you're not providing the data at precisely the clock edge(s) needed. You may want to use the logic analyzer to verify that the data appears exactly in sync with clock edge as required (i.e. at clock rising edge)

As you've probably already noticed, offset 0 and offset 64 are getting the 0x04. So, this adds to the notion of rollover.

Or, it could be that the first data byte of each page is being written "late" and the 0x04 is a result of that.

I don't know if your output port has a SILO so you can send data as in a traditional serial I/O port or do you have to maintain precise bit-for-bit timing (which I presume the `_spi->transfer` would do)

Another thing to try is to write a shorter pattern (e.g. 10 bytes) starting at a non-zero address (e.g. `xhigh = 0; xlow = 4`) and the incrementing pattern and see how things change.

---

**UPDATE:**

From your update, it appears to be the *first* byte of each page [obviously].

From the exploded view of the timing, I notice `SCLK` is not strictly uniform. The pulse width is slightly erratic. Since the write data is sampled on the clock rising edge, this shouldn't matter. But, I wonder where this comes from. That is, is `SCLK` asserted/deasserted by the software (i.e. `transfer`) and `SCLK` is connected to another GPIO pin? I'd be interested in seeing the source for the `transfer` function [or a disassembly].

I've just looked up SPI here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus and it answers my own question.

From that, here is a sample transfer function:

```
/*
 * Simultaneously transmit and receive a byte on the SPI.
 *
 * Polarity and phase are assumed to be both 0, i.e.:
 *   - input data is captured on rising edge of SCLK.
 *   - output data is propagated on falling edge of SCLK.
 *
 * Returns the received byte.
 */
uint8_t SPI_transfer_byte(uint8_t byte_out)
{
    uint8_t byte_in = 0;
    uint8_t bit;

    for (bit = 0x80; bit; bit >>= 1) {
        /* Shift-out a bit to the MOSI line */
        write_MOSI((byte_out & bit) ? HIGH : LOW);

        /* Delay for at least the peer's setup time */
        delay(SPI_SCLK_LOW_TIME);

        /* Pull the clock line high */
        write_SCLK(HIGH);

        /* Shift-in a bit from the MISO line */
        if (read_MISO() == HIGH)
            byte_in |= bit;

        /* Delay for at least the peer's hold time */
        delay(SPI_SCLK_HIGH_TIME);

        /* Pull the clock line low */
        write_SCLK(LOW);
    }

    return byte_in;
}
```

So, the delay times need be at least the ones the ROM needs. Hopefully, you can verify that is the case.

But, I also notice that on the problem byte, the first bit of the data appears to lag its rising clock edge. That is, I would want the data line to be stabilized *before* clock rising edge.

But, that assumes `CPOL=0,CPHA=1`. Your ROM can be programmed for that mode *or* `CPOL=0,CPHA=0`, which is the mode used by the sample code above.

This is what I see from the timing diagram. It implies that the transfer function does `CPOL=0,CPHA=0`:

```
SCLK
          __
         |  |
      ___|  |___

DATA
           ___
          /   \
         /     \
```

This is what I originally expected (`CPOL=0,CPHA=1`) based on something earlier in the ROM document:

```
SCLK
          __
         |  |
      ___|  |___

DATA
        ___
       /   \
      /     \
```

The ROM can be configured to use *either* `CPOL=0,CPHA=0` or `CPOL=1,CPHA=1`. So, you may need to configure these values to match the transfer function (or vice-versa) And, verify that the transfer function's delay times are adequate for your ROM. The SDK may do all this for you, but, since you're having trouble, double checking this may be worthwhile (e.g. See Table 18 et. al. in the ROM document).

However, since the ROM seems to respond well for most byte locations, the timing may already be adequate.

One thing you might also try. Since it's the first byte that is the problem, and here I mean first byte *after* the LSB address byte, the memory might need some additional [and *undocumented*] setup time.

So, after the `transfer(xlow)`, add a small spin loop after that before entering the data transfer loop, to give the ROM time to set up for the write burst [or read burst].

This could be confirmed by starting `xlow` at a non-zero value (e.g. 3) and shortening the transfer. If the problem byte tracks `xlow`, that's one way to verify that the setup time may be required. You'd need to use a different data value for each test to be sure you're not just reading back a stale value from a prior test.

Comment: I have tried many of these things already. I am going to add some more information to the question which may help to answer some of these things. If you wouldn't mind to take a look, I would be very appreciative

Comment: "The ROM can be configured to use either CPOL=0,CPHA=0 or CPOL=0,CPHA=1." - you are wrong. Only 0-0 and 1-1 modes are allowed. PAge 12 of the datasheet.

Comment: @FreddieChopin Yes, you are correct. I misread that page [which is one I pulled that from]

Comment: @CraigEstey. Thank you so much for your detailed response! As you will see the issue has now been resolved thanks to you and Freddie.